# Recyclerview ObjectAnimator

Tags: android

I implemented an animation for the item holder. However, When I tried to slide the view up and down, I noticed that the view items sometimes get animated and sometimes they don't, basically it's very random. Is there a cause for this?

```
private static void transition(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
    ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView, "translationX", -150, 0);
    animator.setDuration(500);
    animator.start();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MovieView holder, int position) {
     .........
     .........

     transition(holder);
}
```

Comment: is that enough? should I post the whole thing? these are the only codes that involved in animation.

Comment: Probably need the whole adapter to see what's going on